# Fit the scrolling to the entire screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, infinite-scroll

Hi I just added the functionality of endless vertical scrolling to my app but I can't figure out how to make size it to the size of the screen. A photo is attached of what i mean. Any help would be appreciated!

[image: ignore the starbucks logo and rectangle lol just placeholders]

Here is my code

```
@implementation GameScene
{
    SKNode* _bglayer;
    SKNode* _gamelayer;
    SKNode* _HUDlayer;
    NSTimeInterval* _dt;
    NSTimeInterval* _lastUpdateTime;


}

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    [self addChild:[self createCharacter] ];
    [self performSelector:@selector(createTile) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];

    _bglayer =[SKNode node];
    [self addChild:_bglayer];
    _gamelayer =[SKNode node];
    [self addChild:_gamelayer];
    _HUDlayer =[SKNode node];
    [self addChild:_HUDlayer];

    SKTexture* backgroundTexture=[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"wallpaper1"];


    SKAction* moveBg =[SKAction moveByX:0 y:-backgroundTexture.size.height*2 duration:0.01*backgroundTexture.size.height];

    SKAction *resetBg =[SKAction moveByX:0 y:backgroundTexture.size.height*2 duration:0];
    SKAction *moveBackgroundForever =[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[moveBg,resetBg]]];

    for (int i=0; i<2 +self.frame.size.height/(backgroundTexture.size.height*2);++i){
        SKSpriteNode* sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:backgroundTexture];

        [sprite setScale:1.0];
        sprite.zPosition=-100;
        sprite.anchorPoint=CGPointZero;
        sprite.position=CGPointMake(350, i*sprite.size.height);
        [sprite runAction:moveBackgroundForever];
        [_bglayer addChild:sprite];

    }
}
```

Comment: Try: `_bglayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);` when you init _bglayer

Comment: That gives me errors and the build fails. Wait after where I declare that SKNode* _bglayer right? (Sorry I'm new at this and pretty confused)

Comment: To make a view fully cover its superview, without auto layout set the view's frame to be the superview's bounds.  In auto layout, set all four edge constraints to zero.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do here is set the content view height according to number of content you need to display in scroll view.

e.g. : if you nee 5 view to display in scroll view then you need to set content size of scroll view to 5*viewHeight*yPos of last object.

But the frame of scroll should be — {{0,0},{self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height}} and content size can be {320,1000} or {320,500} where height and width of content size can be greater than frame of scroll view.